# PowerBI calculate overflow backlog in measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data is as follows:

| Factory ID | Week | CAPACITY | Request |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 1000 | 500 |
| 1 | 22 | 1000 | 1200 |
| 1 | 23 | 1500 | 1600 |
| 1 | 24 | 1500 | 1100 |
| 2 | 21 | 1000 | 500 |
| 2 | 22 | 2000 | 1900 |
| 2 | 23 | 2000 | 1000 |
| 2 | 24 | 2000 | 2500 |
| 3 | 21 | 1000 | 200 |
| 3 | 22 | 1000 | 900 |
| 3 | 23 | 1000 | 1300 |
| 3 | 24 | 1000 | 800 |

I want to calculate backlog in a measure or any other way to have backlog be dynamic based on the factories I select. Backlog is calculated as follows:

Backlog = Capacity - (Request + Previous week backlog); where we have backlog when requests + pre. week backlog exceeds capacity or else it is 0. I cannot move capacity from future weeks, so the backlog would always accumulate going forward

Eg. If I select Factory 1, my backlog should look as follows:

Factory Selected: 1

| Week | Backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 0 |
| 22 | -200 |
| 23 | -300 |
| 24 | -100 |

Factory Selected: 1,2

| Week | Backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 0 |
| 22 | -100 |
| 23 | 0 |
| 24 | -400 |

Factory Selected: 1,3

| Week | Backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 0 |
| 22 | -100 |
| 23 | -500 |
| 24 | 0 |

I have been trying to find a solution since the last 2 days. Let me know if you need any additional details. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Factory 1, Week 22, shouldn't the value be equal to -222 ?

Comment: @AntrikshSharma For factory 1
Week 1 Backlog = 1000 - 500 - 0(backlog from prev week)= 0
Week 2 Backlog = 1000 - 1200- 0(backlog from prev week) = -200
Week 3 Backlog = 1500 - 1600 - 200(backlog from prev week) = -300

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX there are no loops and no recursion, this means that we must write some very ugly loop unrolling dax code. This is a minimal implementation of a working measure, but to make it working in the general case the BacklogWeekNN variables must be added until reaching the maximum possible week depth in the model.

```
Backlog = 
VAR MinWeek = CALCULATE(MIN( T[Week] ), REMOVEFILTERS( T ) )
VAR MaxWeek = MAX( T[Week] )
VAR TAggregated = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALCULATETABLE( VALUES( T[Week] ), T[Week] <= MaxWeek, REMOVEFILTERS( T ) ),
    "@Capacity", CALCULATE( SUM( T[CAPACITY] ), ALLEXCEPT( T, T[Week], T[Factory ID] ) ),
    "@Request", CALCULATE( SUM( T[Request] ), ALLEXCEPT( T, T[Week], T[Factory ID] ) )
    )
VAR BacklogWeek00 = SUMX( FILTER( TAggregated, T[Week] = MinWeek ), [@Capacity] - [@Request] ) + 0
VAR BacklogWeek01 = SUMX( FILTER( TAggregated, T[Week] = MinWeek + 1), [@Capacity] - [@Request] ) + IF(BacklogWeek00 > 0, 0, BacklogWeek00) 
VAR BacklogWeek02 = SUMX( FILTER( TAggregated, T[Week] = MinWeek + 2), [@Capacity] - [@Request] ) + IF(BacklogWeek01 > 0, 0, BacklogWeek01)  
VAR BacklogWeek03 = SUMX( FILTER( TAggregated, T[Week] = MinWeek + 3), [@Capacity] - [@Request] ) + IF(BacklogWeek02 > 0, 0, BacklogWeek02)  
VAR Result = IF(BacklogWeek03 > 0, 0, BacklogWeek03)
RETURN Result
```

This way we can obtain the desired resulting matrix using a slicer to select the factories (I'm afraid there are a few errors in the expected result samples int the question)

[image: matrix for factory 1]

[image: matrix for factories 1 and 2]

[image: matrix for factories 1 and 3]

Edit: I used 'FILTER( TAggregated, T[Week] = MinWeek )' instead of the equivalent CALCULATE/CALCULATTABLE DAX code to avoid context transition happening and because the weeks table has very few rows to be iterated (I can imagine a maximum of a few tens or at maximum hundreds of rows if keeping a few years history)

Comment: This worked. I was trying to run a loop for the backlogweekNN, but wasnt successful. I would need to create 52 backlog variables to forecast for next year.
Thank you so much for this solution. This is a life saver

Comment: Performance will not be very good, but I hope it will be acceptable. The DAX interpreter is a bit slow with this kind of code, but there is no way to use recursion or loops, therefore the only alternative would be to move this calculation in power query or to the datasource to prepare a snapshot table with the backlog pre-computed for the desired factory groups, that should be decided a-priori.